# Flagging how many data are present in a triennial average

Tags: r, flags

I have a dataset considering a yearly time series and a triennial rolling average.

```
country      city          2014   2015   2016   2017   2018   2019  2014-16   2015-17   2016-18  2017-19
US           NYC            2      5      4       5     8       1      3.6       4.6       5.6      4.6 
France       Paris          NA     2      1       4     NA      1      1.5       2        2.5      1.6    
Iran         Tehran         1      NA     NA      NA     1      1      1         NA       1        1
```

Some of the triennial means include  the 3 data, some others 2, 1 or 0. 
I would create a column aside to every triennial flagging if the data considered where 3, 2, 1, or 0 such as:

```
 country      city          2014   2015   2016   2017   2018   2019  2014-16  n. of data 14-16  2015-17 n.of data 20115-17 
US           NYC            2      5      4       5     8       1      3.6        3              etc       etc
France       Paris          NA     2      1       4     NA      1      1.5        2              etc       etc
Iran         Tehran         1      NA     NA      NA     1      1      1          1              etc      etc
```

Any hint?

Comment: what is triennial means? Every 3 columns? And why is your output 3, 2, 1? Also why is your output only up to `14 - 16`?

Comment: Yes, triennial means if every 3 columns.
The output is saying how many data are for that particular triennial. 
I put ' etc'  not to write all the numbers for all the triennials (it seemed confusing in such a narrow space)

Comment: aahhh...ok I get it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `zoo` package which is built for such tasks and basically count all the values that are not NAs, i.e.

```
library(zoo)

t(apply(df[-c(1:2)], 1, function(i)rollapply(i, 3, by = 1, function(j)sum(!is.na(j)))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
#[2,]    2    3    2    2    2    3    3    3
#[3,]    1    0    1    2    3    2    2    2
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Having a look to the package docs. Not sure about the meaning of the output in the example you sent me, though.

Comment: The output is what you expect to get but you will have to bind it to your original data frame, Each column represents the counts of a triennal